# C#: десериализация вложенных объектов

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialize, unserialize

Есть объект класса `A`, который будет помещаться в сессию `ASP.NET` приложения, `sessionState mode="SQLServer"`. класса `A` содержит объекты являются экземплярами классов `A1`, `A2`,....

Для класса `A` можно определить конструктор сериализации, если реализовать интерфейс `ISerializable`:

```
[Serializable]
class A : ISerializable
{ 
    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;
    //...
    protected A(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
    {   }    
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand,SerializationFormatter=true)]
    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
    {   }
}
```

Будут ли при вызываться конструкторы сериализации для объектов `a1`, `a2`, если в классах `A1`, `A2` тоже реализовать интерфейс `ISerializable`?
Если нет, как еще можно вызвать определенные методы `a1`, `a2` при десериализации объекта `A`?

Comment: по идее да. можно протестить, но я уверен на 90% что все будет ОК

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вложенные объекты тоже будут сериализованы (для них будут вызваны их конструкторы). В принципе, Вам не обязательно реализовывать интерфейс `ISerializable`, достаточно атрибута [`Serializable`] и, если надо, то также отметить нужные функции атрибутами [`OnSerializing`], [`OnDesearializing`], [`OnSerialized`],[`OnDeserialized`]

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, отмеченные атрибутами `[OnSerializing], [OnDesearializing], [OnSerialized],[OnDeserialized]` функции будут вызываться при соответствующих событиях?

Comment: Все верно. Все эти функции должны возвращать void и принимать один параметр StreamingContext.